Is there a way to see all the reports generated by gatling together?
I have two gatling simulation classes, say A.java and B.java. I am using gradle for the project. When I run both of the simulation classes by ./gradlew gatlingRun  --all Gatling produces reports for individual simulation classes and stores them in separate folders. I have to open them individually. Is there any way that will show the reports together like JUnit does?

No. Gatling simulations are independent unit. If you want them to execute in the same unit, you must consolidate your scenarios into the same simulations.
You would typically extract your scenarios out of your simulations so you can combine them the way you want in simulations.
